# No module named flask.ext.wtf

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm following @Miguel flask [mega tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms) which is great. In chapter 3 he talks about web forms and flaskWTF extension, installing the extension like this `sudo pip install Flask-WTF` resulted in

> Successfully installed Flask-WTF Flask WTForms Werkzeug Jinja2 itsdangerous markupsafe

but when executing `./run.py` i get an error:

> No module named flask.ext.wtf`

I've google the error and tried to run it like this: `flask/bin/python run.py` but got the same error, also tried `flask/bin/activate`

**Update:** if you run into the same error this is what solved the issue for me
I've installed the following, for sure they are not all needed but since i didn't go one by one to find out which one did the trick i'm listing them all

```
flask/bin/pip install flask-login
flask/bin/pip install flask-openid
flask/bin/pip install flask-mail
flask/bin/pip install sqlalchemy
flask/bin/pip install flask-sqlalchemy
flask/bin/pip install sqlalchemy-migrate
flask/bin/pip install flask-whooshalchemy==0.55a
flask/bin/pip install flask-wtf
flask/bin/pip install pytz
flask/bin/pip install flask-babel
flask/bin/pip install flup
```

Comment: Are you sure that the python version that you are using and the python version that you have installed flask are the same?
Can you add more detailed traceback and code here?

Comment: @liva, did an answer finally work out for you? If so, could you please accept an answer?

Answer (score 21):

The API has changed from:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
```

to:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
```

[See the docs here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/extensions/#extensions)

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck not understanding why the `flask.ext` was not being found. It works in both Py3 and Py2. Apparently there was an API  change but every excample/tutorial seems to use the old syntax.

Answer (score 14):

You are probably using the import style from the older versions:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form, TextField, BooleanField
from flask.ext.wtf import Required
```

The import style changed starting from 0.9.0 version. Be sure to update your imports:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms.fields import TextField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import Required
```

You can find the note about this change in the upgrade section of docs:

https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/upgrade.html#version-0-9-0

Comment: I'm using the new style, as this is the style in the tutorial

Comment: This answer worked perfectly when I downloaded Grinberg's v0.4 zipfile, modified his `app/forms.py` and used it with: `flask==0.10.1`, `wtforms==1.0.5`, and `flask-wtf==0.9.3`

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer in 2016, You need to install 'pip install Flask-WTF' and then change from 'from flask.ext.wtf import Form' to 'from flask_wft import Form'

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I read [steps 1](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) again to check where I slipped.

Remember to install the necessary modules for your project.

In this case the following:

```
flask/bin/pip install flask-login
flask/bin/pip install flask-openid
flask/bin/pip install flask-mail
flask/bin/pip install sqlalchemy
flask/bin/pip install flask-sqlalchemy
flask/bin/pip install sqlalchemy-migrate
flask/bin/pip install flask-whooshalchemy==0.55a
flask/bin/pip install flask-wtf
flask/bin/pip install pytz
flask/bin/pip install flask-babel
flask/bin/pip install flup
```

Since you've created this virtual environment, "flask", all the modules installed are available only in your virtual environment(flask).

Remember to run "flask/Scripts/python run.py" and not "python run.py"

Answer (score 5):

jbub's right, but is addressing a problem you will run into, rather then the problem you're currently having-- the tutorial is dated, and doesn't mention what versions of the library the user should be using, so if you do as the tutorial says you are going to run into problems unless you change your import lines to match what jbub says.

But-- the problem you're currently having isn't that-- if it were, your error would be `No module named flask.ext.wtf.Textfield` at the moment it can't see the library at all.

That means you haven't installed the Flask-WTF library to the correct location, in this case, it looks like it should be installed in your virtual environment, which you seem to have created under a directory called `flask`, to make things a little clearer, I'm going to refer to that directory as `venv`.

The virtual environment is a little room, you need to step into it, then put things on the shelf (install your libraries).
So, first you need to activate your virtual environment, so launch a terminal and navigate to the virtual environment you created (the `venv` dir), and then activate it (walk into the room):

`source bin/activate`

Your console prompt will change to show you've activated it for this terminal-- now your terminal is standing in the room, so you can install your libraries as required, you don't even need `sudo` any more, because your little room is safe for your user to play in, it doesn't effect the world outside it's door.  So lets install flask-wtf (and any other libraries you may need by asking pip):

`pip install flask-wtf` etc.

Now, because you're in the virutal environment, it will launch the version of python that exists there and see all the libraries you've set up, which is what you want.  So while the terminal prompt shows your virtual environment is still active, you can launch your `run.py` file by running `python run.py` and it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Even after changing different import styles and re-installing flask, flask-wtf, if it still does not works :
then in the config.py("config.py may be of different name eg app_config.py etc)

insert the line

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 
'venv/Lib/site-packages'))
```

set the lib path of your own app , in my case it was "venv/Lib/site-packages"

Answer (score 0):

Do this: . flask/bin/activate

Then it'll work properly.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

you can run the command:pip install -U Flask-WTF ,and change to
from flask.ext.wtf import Form 
from wtforms import TextField, BooleanField 
from wtforms.validators import Required